# How to return a customized appearance from ls -R

Tags: bash, recursion

I am a student learning bash and I need to get all the files, directories and everything in the sub-directories and show it to the user in the terminal in a form like this:

```
NAME:    TYPE:
text     :file
doc      :directory
```

text being a file and doc a directory. I do not need to differenciate directories from sub-directories. So far I've come up with this code:

```
for f in $(ls -R)
do
    if[ -d $f ]
    then
        echo "$f : Directory"
    fi
    if[ -f $f ]
    then
        echo "$f : File"
    fi
done | column -t
```

However this code only goes through the current directory and doesn't go through the sub-directories. Any ideas on how I could make this work?

Comment: It's widely discouraged to parse the output of `ls`. Try to stay away from that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) instead.

```
while read file
do
   ...
done < <(find ...)
```

Or with bash 4.0+:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **
do
   ...
done
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what I'm supposed to insert instead of the "..." in the done in the first option. Can you please explain it? Thanks.

Comment: Whatever it is you're currently doing.